# Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported

Tags: c#, api, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

I am trying to get the user details of the related userid given as parameter however I am getting the following error below

```
public async Task<IResult> SendForCustomerAddOperation(BaseParametersModel parameters)
{
    var resultReq = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri($"https://auth.{EnvHelper.ServiceUri}/api/User/GetUserById?userId={parameters.ReceipentUserId}&lazyloading=false"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        Headers =
        {
            { "XApiKey", EnvHelper.AuthApiKey }
        },
    };
    var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(resultReq);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<UserIdentityDto>();

    var notificationDto = new NotificationDto();
    return Send(notificationDto);
}
```

After executing I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: Please add the full text of exception, roll the full printscreen of exception.

Comment: advice: use .NET 6 for IIS and .NET Core for Docker